# How to wait until java compilation of PlantUML diagrams is completed, in Python?

Tags: python, java, wait, plantuml

### Context

I've written a Python code that:

1. First generates PlantUML `.uml` files.
2. Then runs a Java command to locally compile those `.uml` files into `.png` diagrams.
3. Exports those diagrams into a `/images` directory for latex compilation.
4. Then compiles a latex document that integrates those generated PlantUML diagrams.

### Code

The Python that compiles the `.uml` files into `.png` files is:

```
def compile_gantt(relative_plant_uml_java_filepath,relative_src_filepath,src_to_gantt_path):
    os.environ["PLANTUML_LIMIT_SIZE"] = "8192"
    run_bash_command(
        f"java -jar {relative_plant_uml_java_filepath} -verbose {relative_src_filepath}{src_to_gantt_path}"
    )

def run_bash_command(bashCommand):
    # Verbose call.
    subprocess.Popen(bashCommand, shell=True)
    # Silent call.
    #subprocess.Popen(bashCommand, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

And I have written a method that waits until all `.png` files are created:

```
def await_and_verify_compilation_results(self, dir, expected_diagram_filenames,compilation_timout):
        pause_per_iteration=4 #seconds
        
        count=0 # seconds
        while count<compilation_timout:
            all_found=True
            for diagram_filename in expected_diagram_filenames:
                if not os.path.isfile(f"{dir}/{diagram_filename}"):
                    all_found=False
                    print(f"Did not yet find:{dir}/{diagram_filename}")
            print(f"Awaiting compilation of Gantt charts: count={count}/{compilation_timout}.")
            
            # Break while condition.
            if all_found:
                count=compilation_timout+pause_per_iteration
            
            # Continue waiting.
            count=count+pause_per_iteration
            time.sleep(pause_per_iteration)
        
        if not all_found:
            raise Exception("Did not find all gantt diagrams in time!")
        time.sleep(30) # allow extra buffer for all images to be finalised.
```

### Issue

The Python code proceeds before the images are completely generated by the Java process.

This means the images are created but it takes a while before they are actually filled with data. Even when they are filled with data it takes a while before they are completed. For example `some_diagram.png` may increase in file size from 0 kb, to 800 bytes to 1.2 kb over the timespan of a few seconds. So my "await_and_verify_compilation_results` does not wait until the generation of the pictures is completed.

### Question

How can I make the Python code wait until the Java process/PlantUML generation of the `.png` files is completed?

### Considerations

Since the `.png` files are generated automatically, I do not know what their final file size would be. I can set a manual pause of `x` seconds after each `png` to ensure they are completed on my device, but I would not want others with a faster device to have to wait on my buffer. Additionally such a hardcoded loiter may be unreliable, and inefficient compilation-timewise. So I think the most simple solution would be to modify the python function that calls the Java function. I have not yet found out how to make that wait, nor have I found how I can make the Java function signal that is is completed. (The PlantUML `.jar` file is downloaded automatically and I would prefer not to tamper with their file).

Comment: You can use subprocess.call() that waits until the process finish https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gonzalo Odiard already suggested in the comments, the solution could be found by using `subprocess.call` instead of `subprocess.Popen`. So a solution looked like:

```
def run_bash_command(bashCommand):
    # Verbose call.
    subprocess.call(bashCommand, shell=True)
    # Silent call.
    # subprocess.call(bashCommand, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

It was verified on Ubuntu 21.04 Using Python 3.6.